# how to integrate dotnet in embedded?

Tags: .net, embedded

how to integrate dotnet in embedded?

Comment: Could you explain your question in more detail please?

Comment: no where near enough info for a proper answer

Comment: Please use at least on more tag for your technology, thanks.

Comment: ... ok now I'm confused. Web-Development AND embedded? What do you try to do? Make an example please!

Comment: how is babby formed?  Also, the closers and offended need to get a fken life.  +1 and +1 to the correct answers.

Answer (score 2):

I've no idea for what you need it. However, I think this sounds at least perfect to your question (which is not really helpful to help):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework

Answer (score 0):

If your are talking about `ASP.NET` on a embedded device you will find that `.NET Compact Framework` has not built in support for `ASP.NET.`

`OpenNetCF` has a product called [Padan](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/Padarn/tabid/267/Default.aspx) that brings a `ASP.NET` webserver to `Windows CE`.

Answer (score 0):

[Gadgeteer](http://netmf.com/gadgeteer/about.html) sounds like what you're asking for.
You can use the [Gadgeteer Prototype Board](http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/297) with the [.NET Micro Framework](http://www.netmf.com/). [Here](http://www.ghielectronics.com/downloads/FEZ/Beginners%20guide%20to%20NETMF.pdf) you can find a beginners guide.